# Trying to connect Azure ML service to Azure sql databse through pyodbc driver

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, pyodbc

I am trying to run my python script on **Azure ML Service** to fetch data from **Azure SQL Database** using **pyodbc** library.

Please check below code :

```
import pyodbc

class AzureDbConnect:
    # This class is used for azure database connection using pyodbc
    def __init__(self):
        try:
            self.sql_db = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL SERVER};SERVER=<servername>;PORT=1433;DATABASE=<databasename>;UID=<username>;PWD=<password>')

            get_name_query = "select name from contacts"
            names = self.sql_db.execute(get_name_query)
            for name in names:
                print(name)

        except Exception as e:
            print("Error in azure sql server database connection : ", e)
            sys.exit()


class_obj = AzureDbConnect()
```

When running this code on **azure ml service** then **azure ml experiment** failed and with below error inside logs:

```
Running setup.py install for pyodbc: started
    Running setup.py install for pyodbc: finished with status 'error'
[91m    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /azureml-envs/azureml_9d69e3c489cf5128837b0d54c6aae18e/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-zggh4t5x/pyodbc/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-zggh4t5x/pyodbc/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-hx3xndx9/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-zggh4t5x/pyodbc/
    Complete output (13 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'pyodbc' extension
    creating build
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/src
    gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPYODBC_VERSION=4.0.27 -I/azureml-envs/azureml_9d69e3c489cf5128837b0d54c6aae18e/include/python3.6m -c src/buffer.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/src/buffer.o -Wno-write-strings
    cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
    In file included from src/buffer.cpp:12:0:
    src/pyodbc.h:56:17: fatal error: sql.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

How do I fix this error?